# How do the Diggers know so much about Spacers?

Tags: seveneves

In the third act of *Seveneves*, the Spacers encounter the Diggers. The Diggers have been pushing farther into the open, but have made no face-to-face contact with the Spacers before now.

Yet, when Tyuratam discusses the situation with the Diggers, the Diggers know things like the names of the races, and about the political climate of the factions of Spacers - things far more detailed than that could have been gleaned from secretly watching Surveyors.

### How did the Diggers know so much about Spacers, if they've never made contact before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Probably from the Pingers.

Digger scouts could persumably gain a fair bit of knowledge from watching Spacer surveyors, as you touch upon. It's mentioned that they were often out scouting for a long time after they discovered clams were a source of meat, and as shown on page 843 they're very quiet; one Digger scout was able to sneak up on the Spacer Kathree without a sound (getting within five meters of her with a drawn bow). Perhaps they followed and eavesdropped on surveyors for long periods of time, learning some things from their communications.

An additional source of deeper knowledge might however be the Pingers, the subaquatic race of human descendants.

Fifty years prior to the events of the third act of the book, the Diggers established contact with the Pingers, and they've been meeting with them regularly for about five years. Notably, on page 806 Sonar Taxlaw, a Digger, says the Diggers have been receiving intel from the Pingers about the terraforming operations of the Red Spacer faction on page 808 (Einstein and Arjun are both Spacers of the Blue faction):

> "Smiting the Torres Strait with an unceasing storm of bolides," said Sonar Taxlaw, pointing to the narrows where Australia's northern cape almost poked New Guinea in the belly. "Filling it in. Damming the currents. Making a wall against those that swim in the sea."
>   
>   […]
>   
>   "Einstein, did you tell her about Red's illegal terraforming operation here?" And he tapped the same place on the map.
>   
>   "First I've heard of it," Einstein said.
>   
>   "Sonar," Arjun said, "how did you know about that?"
>   
>   "The Pingers told us," Sonar said.

On page 830, it is implied that the Red Spacers might have attempted a diplomatic "first contact" scenario with the Pingers, but that the diplomacy failed due to the terraforming operation mentioned above affecting the Pingers' habitat:

> "If you are going to make first contact with an intelligent alien race," said Cantabrigia Five, "dropping huge strip-mining robots into their homeland might now be your best move."
>   
>   Kathree pondered that one for a bit. […] "So there's a reason they were so keen to make nice with the Diggers."
>   
>   "Having fucked it up spectacularly with the Pingers. Yes."

It's not stated outright, but during this attempt at diplomacy, the Reds probably told the Pingers about the Spacer civilization and some of their history, just like the Blues and the Diggers exchanged similar background information when they had their "first contact" scenario, and the Pingers passed this information on to the Diggers. Presumably the Diggers reciprocated with what observational information they got from watching surveyors.